# replace None values in DataFrame using cell's values of another DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

there are two pandas DataFrames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['ann', 'maxim', 'ann', 'maxim'],
    'surname': [ 'smith', 'shwarz','smith', 'shwarz'],
    'date': ['2020.01.01',  '2020.01.01', '2020.03.05','2020.03.05'],
    'mark_1': [None,'B', 'A', None],
    'mark_2': [None,'B', None,'A'],
    'mark_3': [None,None, 'A', 'C']
       })
```

| name | surname | date | mark_1 | mark_2 | mark_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ann | smith | 2020.01.01 | None | None | None |
| maxim | shwarz | 2020.01.01 | B | B | None |
| ann | smith | 2020.03.05 | A | None | A |
| maxim | shwarz | 2020.03.05 | None | A | C |

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['ann', 'maxim'],
    'surname': [ 'smith', 'shwarz'],
    'mark_1': ['Z','X'],
    'mark_2': ['H','F'],
    'mark_3': ['P','Y']
       })
```

| name | surname | mark_1 | mark_2 | mark_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ann | smith | Z | H | P |
| maxim | shwarz | X | F | Y |

I need:

| name | surname | date | mark_1 | mark_2 | mark_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ann | smith | 2020.01.01 | Z | H | P |
| maxim | shwarz | 2020.01.01 | B | B | Y |
| ann | smith | 2020.03.05 | A | H | A |
| maxim | shwarz | 2020.03.05 | X | A | C |

But function`df1.isnull(df2)` replaces only first rows with the similar names and surnames:

| name | surname | date | mark_1 | mark_2 | mark_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ann | smith | 2020.01.01 | Z | H | P |
| maxim | shwarz | 2020.01.01 | B | B | Y |
| ann | smith | 2020.03.05 | A | None | A |
| maxim | shwarz | 2020.03.05 | None | A | C |

As I understand, it should be something like CASE statement from SQL, but I can't find the answer.

Special respect if you can explain the same function for two PySpark DataFrames!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
new_df = (
    df1.set_index(['name', 'surname'])
        .combine_first(df2.set_index(['name', 'surname']))
        .reset_index()
)
```

`new_df`:

```
    name surname        date mark_1 mark_2 mark_3
0    ann   smith  2020.01.01      Z      H      P
1    ann   smith  2020.03.05      A      H      A
2  maxim  shwarz  2020.01.01      B      B      Y
3  maxim  shwarz  2020.03.05      X      A      C
```

Optional [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
new_df = (
    df1.set_index(['name', 'surname'])
        .combine_first(df2.set_index(['name', 'surname']))
        .reset_index()
        .sort_values('date')
)
```

`new_df`:

```
    name surname        date mark_1 mark_2 mark_3
0    ann   smith  2020.01.01      Z      H      P
2  maxim  shwarz  2020.01.01      B      B      Y
1    ann   smith  2020.03.05      A      H      A
3  maxim  shwarz  2020.03.05      X      A      C
```

Comment: I tried combine_first without set_index, was it the problem? Is it  the reason why python   take uses something like non-greedy search?

Comment: pandas DataFrame alignment is based on the _index_ without `set_index` `combine_first` would try to pair row `0` in `df1` with row `0` in `df2`. By setting the index, now `combine_first` is aligned by `name` and `surname` and will combine where they match.

Answer (score 1):

Using Spark you must join the dataframes and use `coalesce` function to replace null values:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as f


df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['ann', 'maxim', 'ann', 'maxim'],
    'surname': [ 'smith', 'shwarz','smith', 'shwarz'],
    'date': ['2020.01.01',  '2020.01.01', '2020.03.05','2020.03.05'],
    'mark_1': [None,'B', 'A', None],
    'mark_2': [None,'B', None,'A'],
    'mark_3': [None,None, 'A', 'C']
})
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(df1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['ann', 'maxim'],
    'surname': [ 'smith', 'shwarz'],
    'mark_1': ['Z','X'],
    'mark_2': ['H','F'],
    'mark_3': ['P','Y']
})
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(df2)

df3 = df1.alias('l').join(df2.alias('r'), on=['name', 'surname'], how='left')
df3 = (df3
       .select('name', 
               'surname', 
               'date', 
               f.coalesce('l.mark_1', 'r.mark_1').alias('mark_1'), 
               f.coalesce('l.mark_2', 'r.mark_2').alias('mark_2'), 
               f.coalesce('l.mark_3', 'r.mark_3').alias('mark_3')))

(df3
 .sort('date')
 .show(truncate=False))
# +-----+-------+----------+------+------+------+
# |name |surname|date      |mark_1|mark_2|mark_3|
# +-----+-------+----------+------+------+------+
# |ann  |smith  |2020.01.01|Z     |H     |P     |
# |maxim|shwarz |2020.01.01|B     |B     |Y     |
# |ann  |smith  |2020.03.05|A     |H     |A     |
# |maxim|shwarz |2020.03.05|X     |A     |C     |
# +-----+-------+----------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I thought about coalesce, but couldn't understand how use it...